# How do I use PHPUnit with CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpunit

I have unsuccessfully tried to use [PHPUnit 4.4.2](https://phpunit.de/) with [CodeIgniter 3](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter) .

> CodeIgniter 3 is the branch under active development and it support phpunit

**i don't know what is wrong with my code here .**

```
<?php
// post_test.php
class Post_test extends CI_TestCase {
  private $ci_obj;

  public function setUp() {
    $loader = $this->ci_core_class('loader');
    $this->load = new $loader();
    $this->ci_obj = $this->ci_instance();
    $this->ci_set_core_class('model', 'CI_Model');
    $test =  $this->ci_vfs_clone('application/models/post.php');
    $this->load->model('post');
  }

  public function testGetAllPosts() {
    $posts = $this->ci_obj->post->getAll();
    $this->assertEquals(5, count($posts));
  }
}
```

and the model

```
<?php
//post.php
class Post extends CI_Model {

  public function getAll() {
    return array(
      array('title'=>'post 1','content'=>'...'),
      array('title'=>'post 2','content'=>'...'),
      array('title'=>'post 3','content'=>'...'),
      array('title'=>'post 4','content'=>'...'),
      array('title'=>'post 5','content'=>'...'),
    );
  }
}
```

it gives me this error

```
............S............................PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getChild() on a non-object in /path/tests/mocks/ci_testcase.php on line 241

Fatal error: Call to a member function getChild() on a non-object in /path/tests/mocks/ci_testcase.php on line 241
/path/tests
```

Comment: What is your PHPUnit Version ?

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya PHPUnit 4.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `parent::setUp();` inside `setUp()` function.

`public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    ...`

Rename model name from `application/models/post.php` to `application/models/Post.php` and also fix the path of `ci_vfs_clone` in the test file.